# Calculate Length in Custom Attribute Magento

Tags: magento

I'm killing myself trying to find the right solution for this problem.  Here is my issue:

Selling Wires:

1. We will say a wire is $5.00
2. If you want 1 foot its $5.00
3. If you want 2 feet its $10.00
4. ...

Each foot isn't a separate SKU.  Its a recalculation of the total. Thats it.  Really easy, but for some reason incredibly difficult in Magento.

How would I code this?  Any ideas?

****UPDATE***

These are configurable products.  Didn't think of that in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without adding additional attributes or logic is sell by the foot.

Have your SKU as `wire-1-foot` for example and use Magento's built-in [tier pricing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing) to customise your pricing for multiple quantities, aka multiple feet of wire.

You will probably also want to customise the block around the quantity field to make this a clearer for customers.

**EDIT:**
You could also consider grouped products as they behave slightly differently, e.g. http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2010/11/tiered-pricing-on-configurable-products/

Comment: Simple product SKUs not the configurable products, I'm assuming.  Do you know a way to make this all a dropdown combobox?

Comment: I edited above about grouped products, they're worth a look. Doing a drop down is a little harder. Ideally I expect you want this to work off the simple product min and max quantities, to display the dropdown for that range. Take a look here there may be something of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869703/replace-quantity-input-box-with-dropdown-quantity-increments